# We're going to need a tag synonym for jenkins and hudson

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

Might as well get ahead of the curve on this one.

Comment: ..........what?

Comment: @Jon: Probably a reference to this: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Community-vote-landslide-Hudson-to-become-Jenkins-1180110.html

Comment: A link would have been nice

Comment: @Henk sorry about that.

Comment: I don't think a tag synonym is the answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78549/how-should-we-handle-questions-for-software-that-has-been-renamed-or-forked

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be hitting this issue regularly. Using Jenkins, but almost everything also applies to Hudson, almost every question and answer are applicable to both still today, 2 years later...

I think some kind of special tag is needed, which would mean "Hudson and derivatives", but I have no idea what would be a good solution for SE sites (both technially and policy-wise).